# Markov chain state reached earlier than other state

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Consider a Markov chain with $S={1, 2, 3, 4}$ and transition Matrix:
$P=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1/2 & 1/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

We start in state 3. What is the chance that from this state that we reach state 1 earlier than state 4?

I should first make matrix $P*$, the absorption matrix.
$P^*=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

Yet, my answers say we should make this rowvector:
$f=\begin{bmatrix} 
1\\
x \\
y \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$
Where $x$ is the chance that we start in state 3 and reach 1 earlier than 4 and $y$ the state that we start in 2 and reach 1 earlier than 4. However, I do not understand why $f(2)=x$ and $f(3)=y$, shouldn't that be reversed?

Comment: If really the question is to know the chance, starting from state 3, to reach state 1 earlier than state 4, one may want to note that p(3,1)=p(3,4)=1/2 hence *the first step* is all one needs...

Comment: That is what I thought too, but the answers say $x=1/4$, which is why I am  confused.